# Correction to Newton's law of Gravity for dark energy

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, space-expansion, estimation, dark-energy

Is there any correction to Newtons law of Gravity that takes into account the expansion of the universe?

Comment: Yes and No. It's modified is for dark non-baryonic matter and It's called MOND - Modified Newtonian Dynamics. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7661. There's BIMOND theory which produces a parameter in the cosomological constant.

Comment: @CinaedSimson that appears to be an answer

Answer (score 0):

Long before you can address that you need to switch from Newton's description of gravity to Einstein's. General relativity includes the Einstein field equation $R_{ab}-\frac{R-2\Lambda}{2}g_{ab}=\kappa T_{ab}$. Dark energy [is represented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant#Equation) by $\Lambda$. It's difficult to relate this back to Newtonian physics because a point mass's gravity in an otherwise flat spacetime has $R=0$.